Data not updated performing auth login + redirect back to page
I'm learning svelte and set up a small project.
Problem: A non-authenticated user navigates to /notes and gets redirected to /login. After performing the login, user gets redirected back to /notes and should see a list of notes.
After getting logged in and being sent back to /notes, there's still no data displayed (same page displayed as for a non-auth user, seems like svelte displays the SSR content generated when user wasn't logged in yet..?) When I refresh the page, the data updates. My guess is that I'm misunderstanding reactive declarations or need to trigger the load function again..?
Many thanks for any support on this, as I'm getting more and more confused.
Here the 5 relevant files:
routes/(authed)/notes/+page.ts => simply load and return data
export const load: PageLoad = async ({ fetch }) => {
  const res = await fetch("my-third-party-api.com/notes")

  return {
    data: await res.json()
  };
};

routes/(authed)/notes/+page.svelte => display list of notes
<script lang="ts">
  import type { PageData } from './$types';
  export let data: PageData;
  $: notes = data.notes;
</script>

<h1>List:</h1>

{#each notes as { title, body }}
  <div class="note">
    <h3>{title}</h3>
    <p>Body: {body}</p>
  </div>
{/each}

routes/(authed)/+layout.server.ts => check if user is logged in, if not, redirect to /login
export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ url, locals }) => {
  if (locals.user) {
    [...]
  } else {
    redirect(303, `/login?redirectTo=${url.pathname}`);
  }
};

routes/login/+page.svelte => let the user log in + trigger login form action
<script lang="ts">
  import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
  import { page } from '$app/stores';
  const redirectTo = $page.url.searchParams.get('redirectTo') || '/';
</script>

<h1>log in</h1>

<form method="POST" action="/?/login&redirectTo={redirectTo}" use:enhance>
  <label for="username">
    username:
    <input type="text" required name="username" id="username" />
  </label>
  <label for="password">
    password:
    <input type="password" required name="password" id="password" />
  </label>
  <button>Log In</button>
</form>

routes/+page.server.ts => perform login action, redirect back to the page the user initially came from before being redirected to /login (=> back to /notes, this time logged in)
export const actions = {
  login: async ({ request, cookies, fetch, url }) => {
    ... get form data, perform log in ...
    ... set cookies ...
    
    redirect(303, url.searchParams.get('redirectTo') ?? '/');
  }
},

... more named actions ...

Tried to go through many documentation, tinker with load functions, reactive declarations and go through tutorials.

The load function in routes/(authed)/notes/+page.ts was running on the client side after the redirect and was sending out a request to a credentialled route, hence no data back. Changed it to +page.server.ts and working fine, as the cookies are included now.
